# I can't access to a payload received on my application's server and import it into the frontend part

Tags: javascript, axios, httprequest, fetch-api

My webapp is running on a node express server. The service gateway sends it a payload. I would like, through a javascript file, to access the data of this payload and import them into the frontend part of my web application, more precisally in a form. Following the code of the server receiving the payload and the javascript sending the request

---

```
//server.js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.use(express.json()); // 

 // Configurazione CORS
app.use(
cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:8000",
  methods: "GET, POST, OPTIONS",
  allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, application/json, charset = charset=utf-8"
 })
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./issuer/index.html"));
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    // Ottieni i dati dalla richiesta POST
    const payload = req.body;
    console.log(payload);
    
    const didSubject = payload.did;
    const scope = payload.scope;

    // Crea un oggetto con i valori da restituire come parte della risposta
    const responseData = {
      did:didSubject,
      scope:scope
  };
    //console.log(responseData);
    //console.log(didSubject);
    //console.log(scope);
    res.json(responseData);     
});

const server = app.listen(8080);
const portNumber = server.address().port;
console.log(`MetaWallet Issuer Server is running on http://localhost:${portNumber}`);
```

```
//reques
VCRequestButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Accept-Charset", "application/json");
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "did": "string",
      "scope": "string",
      }),
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
  axios.post("http://localhost:8080", requestOptions)
  .then(response => {
    // Richiesta riuscita
    const responseData = response.data;
    const didSubject = responseData.did;
    const scope = responseData.scope;
    //console.log("didSubject:", didSubject);
    //console.log("scope:", scope);

    // Utilizza did e scope come desideri
    document.querySelector('input[name="subject-did"]').value = responseData.did
    document.querySelector('input[name="credential-type"]').value = responseData.scope
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Errore nella richiesta
    console.error("Errore nella richiesta", error);
  });
```

The data reaches the server, in fact I can print them on screen throug .log commands. When I execute the request to retrieve the payload values and import them into the form "undefined" is displayed (example in the picture).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc91w.png)

Comment: `console.log(response)` and see what you got